# Writing Boolean statements in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing a exercise that asks:

"A person gets a 50% discount if they are a student aged between 10 and 20 years".

Why is my boolean statement failing?

```
package exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FareDiscountApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonClass discountPerson;

        discountPerson = new PersonClass();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the peron's age: ");
        discountPerson.age = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the peron's weight:");
        discountPerson.weight = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Is the person a student (true/false:");
        discountPerson.student = keyboard.nextBoolean();
        System.out.println("Please enter the peron's gender (M/F");
        discountPerson.gender = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        if (discountPerson.age > 65)
        {
            System.out.println("This peron's bus discount is 100%");
        }
        else if ((discountPerson.student == !(false)) && (discountPerson.age > 10 && < 20))
        {


    }

}
```

Comment: this doesnt look good: ***discountPerson.student == !(false)***

Comment: not even talking about this invalid : ***(discountPerson.age > 10 && < 20)***

Comment: There's no need to put `!(false)`.  Just use `true`.  Then get rid of `== true` since you never need to say that for a boolean.  Finally: don't use shortcuts like (> 10 && < 20) if you're trying to compare the same value.  Java doesn't understand that.  You need to put the whole variable name in the condition: `discountPerson.age > 10 && discountPerson.age < 20`.

Comment: Thanks guys, read everyone's comments and appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to compare boolean values, see here what your expression evaluates to:

```
discountPerson.student == !(false)
=> discountPerson.student == true
=> true == true
=> true
```

Instead, you can just write:

```
if (discountPerson.student && (discountPerson.age > 10 && discountPerson.age < 20) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The way you explained it made sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
else if (discountPerson.student && discountPerson.age > 10 && discountPerson.age < 20)
```

as you are missing comparing something to the `20`

Notice how I simplified the first comparision and got rid of the unnecessary brackets

Comment: Thanks for the help Scary Wombat :)

Answer (score 1):

That would have to be:

```
if (discountPerson.student && discountPerson.age > 10 && discountPerson.age < 20) {

    // ...
}
```